# how to fix unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, integer

I want to encrypt the decimal value of s, but i got Error unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow: 'list' and 'int'. How to fix it to get the output in decimal?

```
#Hexadecimal to decimal
def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
s = "66a9b2d0b1baf7932416c65a28af3c89"    

decimal = hex_to_decimal(s)
print("s in decimal: ", decimal)


#Encryption
e = 79
n = 3220

def mod(x,y):
        if (x<y):
            return x
        else:
            c = x%y
            return c
    
def enk_blok(m):
    decimalList = [int(i) for i in str(m)]
    cipher = []
    for i in decimalList:
        cipherElement = mod(decimalList**e, n)
        cipher.append(cipherElement)
    return ''.join(cipher)

c = enk_blok(decimal)
print("The result: ", c)
```

Comment: `decimalList**e` is undefined. What does it even *mean* to raise a list to a power? The error message informs you that in Python that is simply undefined. Perhaps you intend `[x**e for x in decimalList]`

Comment: Also you want probably `return "".join(map(str, cipher))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have written `decimalList` instead of `i` in  for loop:

```
def enk_blok(m):
    decimalList = [int(i) for i in str(m)]
    cipher = []
    for i in decimalList:
        cipherElement = mod(decimalList**e, n) # replace decimalList with i
        cipher.append(cipherElement) 
    return ''.join(cipher)
```

Also, this line `return ''.join(cipher)` will raise an error, because `cipherElement` is an integer, and `join` method doesn't work with the list of integers, you should cast `cipherElement` to `str`.